# Is the homogeneous BCs have no effect for solving PDE with D'Alembert?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, linear-pde

Suppose i have wave equation with 2 BCs (Boundary Conditions), one of them is Non homogeneous and 2 homogeneous ICs (Initial Conditions).

If I have a non-homogeneous boundary condition do I have to make it homogeneous first then it will make me able to solve PDE with the D'Alembert formula?

Does it mean that the homogeneous boundary conditions have no effect on the execution of the D'Alembert formula?

Please give me the best explanation. I have read 2 books, journals and site. But i still confused with the BCs, because some examples doesn't give that BC. But, many of them always included the ICs. So i can't find the answer. Please help me.

Comment: Could you clarify your first sentence, please? It seems that English is not your native language, and it's perfectly ok, but I really have some trouble understanding the problem you describe.

Comment: What I usually think of as the D'Alembert formula is for the wave equation on the whole line. What are you thinking of as the D'Alembert formula?

Comment: Ok, could you then give some of the examples you talk about at the end of your question, so we can understand better what you are struggling with?

Comment: Given PDE with BCs and ICs

$u_{tt}=u_{xx},\quad 0<x<1,\,0<t<\infty \\ u(0,t)=0 \\ u(1,t)=\sin\,t \\ u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0,\quad 0<x<1$

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No problem! English is not the problem here, I'm still not sure what you don't understand... Could you give two examples, one you understand, one you don't? Don't worry about the English, just detail the math. (And please write it inside the question text, rather than in the comments)

Comment: Ok as far as i know, from several literatures if i have nonhomogeneous BC i have to assume $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+w(x)$ then i take derivative w.r.t $t$ and $x$ and plug in to the original equation, and BC and it will end up with homogeneous BC. The point is, i confused with the BC on the PDE that i have to solve with the D'Alembert. Is the BC information is useless. I mean it doesn't effect on my work? Or i have to use the BC? I hope u understand what i mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

You are right about what you do when you have a linear PDE with some inhomogeneous boundary conditions. 
You split $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+w(x, t)$ with:

- $u$ the function you are searching for,
- $v$ a function which verifies the BCs,
- $w$ a function which verifies the PDE.

Then when you plug in the decomposition in the PDE, $w$ goes away and leaves only the $v$ with the BCs. The hard part is to find a suitable $v$, then.

The goal is to find a simple form for $v$, one which is automatically solution to the PDE because its derivatives of a certain order are 0, for instance.